# How do I enable welcome mode in QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Does anyone know how to enable the 'welcome mode' in QtCreator? From what I can see, it should just be an icon on the left-hand side, but my QtCreator only lists 'Edit, Design, Debug, Projects, Analyze and Help'.

I have not disabled the welcome mode on the commandline either.

QtCreator-3.2.0, Qt4.8.6 & Qt5.3.1, Fedora 19

Comment: I think you may be missing the "Welcome" plugin. Can you check if the folder "<qtcreator-install>/lib/qtcreator/plugins/QtProject" contains "Welcome.dll" and "Welcome.pluginspec"? You should also have some qml files in "<qtcreator-install>/share/qtcreator/welcomescreen".

Comment: I have no 'welcome pluginspec' and nothing that looks like 'welcome.dll' (would that not be something like libWelcome.so ?). The qml for the welcomescreen however is there.

Comment: Could be related to [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1072126)?

Comment: It looks like it is indeed. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The welcome screen is only built and enabled when compiling under Qt 5.1 or newer. That's because it uses modern QML and depends on features that were not present in Qt 5.0 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Go to help > About plugins > Core.

In that tab, search for the "Welcome" option and check the box next to it.
Then press the close button and it will restart the program.